# Should wild card characters (* and ?) be allowed for fieldMatching in elastic search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-string, wildcard, string-search

I am getting a response if I search the details using wildCard characters in the elastic search for fieldMatch.Is this as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Field queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/field-query/) are a version of [query_string queries](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/), which support using * and ? as wildcards. So, it is expected that the following will return results for "elasticsearch".

```
{
    "field" : { "engine" : "elastic*ch" }
}

{
    "field" : { "engine" : "elasticsea?ch" }
}
```